# List comprehension & error: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I am trying to create equally sized samples between the values of x below which are greater or equal to 0.45:

```
x
array([ 0.  ,  0.05,  0.1 ,  0.15,  0.2 ,  0.25,  0.3 ,  0.35,  0.4 ,
        0.45,  0.5 ,  0.55,  0.6 ,  0.65,  0.7 ,  0.75,  0.8 ,  0.85,
        0.9 ,  0.95])

x2=x[x>=0.45]

sample=np.array([np.arange(0,x2[i],x2[i]*0.1) for i in xrange(x2)])
```

or

```
sample=[]
for i in xrange(x2):
     sample.append(np.arange(0.0,x2[i],x2[i]*0.1))
```

But I am getting the following error each time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

When I try with individual values of x, i.e. for one instance of the loop, it works. It seems that Python expects one value only in 'sample' and not a bunch of arrays. Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I guess that you could solve the task using numpy builtin stuff (i.e. `np.linspace` or something similar).

Second, your actual problem here is the call

```
xrange(x2)
```

`xrange` expects an integer so numpy tries to convert `x2`, however, since it's an array that won't work. I guess you wanted to write

```
xrange(len(x2))
```